# Should the "ask about own post" feature be enabled here on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, new-users

In March 2016, a new feature was introduced to Stack Exchange sites: the ability for users without enough rep to participate in meta to [ask about their own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274518/a-way-for-new-users-to-ask-about-their-post-specifically). When it was rolled out initially, it was enabled on most sites, but disabled on localized sites (due to a lack of translations) and here on Stack Overflow (as a temporary measure, to see if it would be disruptive or not).

However, the feature was never enabled here on Stack Overflow, even after a long period. Taking a brief look into its use on other meta sites, it seems to be useful and non-disruptive. In addition, as a Meta Stack Exchange regular, I can tell you that we do get people asking about their own Stack Overflow posts on Meta Stack Exchange; they post there because they have less than 5 rep here. Those users go on to have a bad experience because they're told to post here, except they can't. We gave users of other sites a way around that by implementing the above feature, but, again, it's not enabled here.

Given the above, should this feature be enabled here on Stack Overflow? Any thoughts about it?

Do note that this feature isn't presented anywhere in the main site UI; it's only shown when the user comes here to this meta and attempts to ask a question here.

**Update:** Given the positive reception of this post, I filed a formal request to enable this feature: [Enable the “ask about own post” feature for low-rep users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/enable-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-for-low-rep-users)

**Update 2:** This is now [enabled here on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/enable-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-for-low-rep-users/366734#366734), though it is subject to being disabled if many of the resulting new-user posts are of low quality. [Click here to search for questions asked by low-rep users using this feature.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22i+have+a+question+about+my+stack+overflow+post%22)

Comment: Not active here, but as a side observer think it should be fine to at least try. If after a while we see it's being abused too much, turn it off again. Otherwise, leave it enabled.

Comment: @Martin feel free to post answer explaining why.

Comment: @Maroun has already explained. Enabling such a 'feature' would just blow up the current 'cool trend' of hammering skilled/experienced SO user-moderators as hostile bullies,  Lets face it - if that set of users was unionized, they would have downed logins and gone on strike long ago:(

Comment: @MartinJames We are talking users with < 5 rep here. Do they have spent enough time on this site to be aware of any such “cool trends”?

Comment: Or have failed badly. But people do it on Twitter anyway. At least here we can win a few over.

Comment: @HermannDöppes I have no idea how much time a user with <5 votes has on the site.  All I can see is when that particular account was opened.

Comment: I would definitely support this feature if the 'explain my down and close votes', (and any other stuff that might get a word in), was directed to a separate 'NewMeta' site or a meta-triage queue.  Those meta posters who support the implementation of this feature can then handle the posts and.or do the triage.  Non-ranty posts can be migrated to meta-proper.  Yup - good idea!  Have an upvote!

Comment: I don't think anyone can at this moment say how many questions this feature will produce. I'm absolutely in favor of trying it out to see how well it works. Why not start with a 3-month phase and evaluate what happened afterwards. If it worked well, we'll keep it, if not then remove it. Shutting down features requests just because they could turn out bad without having any real data except for guesses on what will happen is a very bad trend on meta. There are no features that have a 0% chance of turning out bad.

Comment: @BDL There's also data showing it worked well on other sites

Comment: SO meta already gets a significant number of "why you downvote me" questions.  Not infrequently posted to SO and then migrated to meta.  They rarely end well, not in the least because the set of answers is a small one.

Comment: @BDL Here's another bad trend - suggesting features that involve a significant amount of extra work for 'other people'.  For instance, that hardy perennial 'comment on downvotes' is usually suggested by users who hardly ever downvote:(

Comment: If enabled, the user needs to be warned of the Meta effect.

Comment: @HermannDöppes I believe you got it backwards, it's actually the users with <5 rep, that lack experience with SO, that are creating that trend outside of SO, such as on twitter. The vast majority of all people that wine about SO on other social media don't have reputable accounts, asked a single question, then went all unique butterfly to their friends.

Comment: I'll just be curious to see what the percentage of such meta posts will be "answer my question" posts. (Also the aforementioned "why was my question downvoted" posts.)

Comment: @BoltClock makes a good point. We get a few of those per day and have to close/delete them, (or a mod sees it first and exterminates it).  Such posts are obviously way-off-topic, but get posted here anyway.   Going on that, how many more on-topic 'explain my downvotes' should we expect from the 1-5 group?

Comment: @MartinJames one can argue that this point is in favor of this proposal. To me for example this curiosity is a main reason why I support enabling the feature (_provided of course that we will have an option to disable it back if needed_). Posts from <5 rep users I've seen at other metas were nothing special content wise (I recall only on true gem) and I think it won't be better at MSO but I was really surprised how few were there and would want to learn if such a scarcity will also be the case for Stack Overflow

Comment: @gnat Given the current state of this feature (enabled on most sites yet disabled on a few: SO and all localized sites), I'd say it's pretty easy to enable or disable it on a particular site.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

So moderator on a smaller site where this is enabled and...

At least for us, *use of this feature* is remarkably rare - and I can't remember a case of abuse off the top of my head. The barrier of entry is non trivial - you actually need to know the feature exists, that posting a link of your post unlocks meta usage and at this point you've managed to expend a non trivial amount of effort learning how to use it.

You literally know MSE exists (and not just as a place to ask off topic questions), *or* know that meta SO exists, try to ask a question there, and take advantage of the option to post a link to your own question.

And well.

Its non trivial and takes more effort than simply throwing a question on a site. You've intrinsically sieved out a good chunk of folk who're not taking an interest in how things work.As such don't really see that many users wandering in and its a non trivial amount of effort to find your way in - unlike MSE...

> This feature is now live on all meta sites except the international sites (waiting on translations) and meta.StackOverflow (to ensure that this doesn't cause a lot of undue disruptions on other sites first).

And well, I've personally not seen much "undue disruptions" so far so, this might not be a bad idea despite SO's much bigger scale.

Comment: To _know_ about it may comes through a comment saying "_Welcome to Stack Overflow, you may ask about your own post on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)_".

Comment: I assume there would be some events that precipitated that comment

Comment: @Cœur I suppose it's too much to hope that anyone leaving such a comment wouldn't also include a warning of the Meta effect?

Comment: @BSMP I didn't thought about that, you're right.

Comment: @Cœur Well, it was a sincere question 'cause maybe people would but now that I think about it, the feature itself ought to warn people too.

Comment: Doesn't this indicate that a better job explaining this feature should be made. I don't know if it has a help page or it is described outside MSE

Answer (score -4):

With [~7.7k questions/day](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic), Stack Overflow is by far the most busy in the Stack Exchange sites.

Many newcomers skip the tour and the guides, and they only care about their question being answered. With the ability of asking about every question you post on Meta, we might increase the risk of having a flood.

My feeling is that this feature worked on other sites because they significantly have less traffic than Stack Overflow. I tend to disagree with such a feature request, but on the other hand, we can always turn off features if they don't help in the long term.

---

Clarification: I'm not saying we shouldn't give new users a chance to improve their posts. There are many ways to help a user improving his post:

- Comment a link to the guides
- Explain why you downvoted
- Edit and improve where possible
- Link to a Meta post (there are many) which's asking "how to improve my post"

I vote for this approach rather than allowing questions on Meta.

Comment: Please see question edit. I don't believe users are actually told about this feature unless they actually attempt to ask a question here, and judging by the low (but regular) instances of questions about own posts being asked on MSE, I don't think it's a huge burden.

Comment: It hasn't been 7.7K for a long time.  Ah, those halcyon days before Oct 2012.  After peaking at 11.9K it is today at 10.6K.  Not so sure how this went wrong, probably smearing it across weekend days and not counting deleted questions.

Comment: @gparyani My answer still holds.

Comment: I don't believe that gimme-codez users are so keen on understanding why their questions were downvoted or closed. And if they do, they are probably the type of users who want to be better users, why not give them the opportunity?

Comment: @jjj I'm not saying we shouldn't give them opportunity, but it's not necessarily by allowing them to post on Meta. We can reference to the guides or provide a good explanation in the comments.

Comment: I think you are overestimating the number of newcomers who "only care about their question being answered" that would take the time to use this feature to post on Meta.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to only unlock for users who have the "Informed" badge?

Comment: It seems a leap to say that it would be problematic on SO because of the higher traffic, when another answer comments that they've seen zero misuse on another site.  It MIGHT become a problem due to traffic, but it seems unlikely and worth trying

Comment: I didn't say, even once, that we shouldn't try it. I'm just suggesting alternatives, just in case..