# Enable the “ask about own post” feature for low-rep users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, new-users

Following the discussion at [Should the "ask about own post" feature be enabled here on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366373/should-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-be-enabled-here-on-stack-overflow), the reception appears to be positive and generally in favor of enabling that feature here.

For context, on other sites in the Stack Exchange network (except localized sites), there exists a feature that allows users without the required rep to participate in meta to ask about their own posts. It's currently disabled here, but I propose that it should be enabled, because it doesn't appear to cause disruption on other sites and due to the positive community consensus above.

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, on a regular basis, we get people asking about their own Stack Overflow posts, and those questions are (understandably) closed as "off-topic; pertains to only one specific site". This leaves users with a bad experience because they're caught in limbo: being told to post here about their question, but they can't because they don't have enough rep, etc. That's one major thing that the above feature was intended to address.

It's also worth noting that users are only shown this feature if they come here and attempt to ask a question here. This feature isn't presented anywhere in the main site UI.

Can we have this feature, please?

Comment: Cautiously in favor. If it becomes too disruptive, we'll just have to switch it off again.

Comment: Hmm.. I did not realize it was a problem for SE main.  OK, turn it on as a trial, after all, I can see the poster rep and I don't have to open 'explain vote' meta posts from 1-5'ers if I don't want to:)

Comment: So far I’ve just seen this feature abused in most cases. Should we disable it again?

Comment: @Xufox So far, it's only been used six times over the course of more than six weeks. Most of the posters are legitimately confused newbies, not abusive users. I think it's at a very reasonable level.

Comment: @gparyani _“So far, it's only been used six times”_ — you’re not counting all the deleted “I have a question about my post, plz answer!” Meta posts.

Comment: @Xufox You have evidence? We both are <10k, so let's see what the 10k+ users have to say.

Comment: @gparyani I constantly have the [newest Meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=1&sort=newest) opened as a tab. Since it offers the automatic update feature, I can see when a new question appears and catch some of those that improperly use this feature. I guess I could start collecting each of those questions and making screenshots of them.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ok... Let's *try* this.

[image: You must have at least 5 reputation on Stack Overflow to ask a question on meta, but you may ask a question about your own Stack Overflow post specifically.]

Most of the feedback I saw - both here and when I asked around privately - fell into two buckets:

1. Folks asking for help improving their questions are going to have a bad time here
2. Folks are going to ask for things we cannot / should not help with (read: they're going to ask programming questions here instead of asking *about* programming questions they've already asked on the main site)

If #2 happens with too much frequency, we're just going to have to turn this off again; the volume of people coming through Stack Overflow may simply be too high to lower the bar here.

Failure-mode #1 is kinda up to all of *us* though. If we're gonna invite folks to ask questions about their questions here, **we have to actually welcome those meta-questions** - otherwise, what's the point of doing this? So y'all can't be passive about this: if someone asks a reasonable question about their main-site question, edit it, upvote it, and **answer it**. Yeah, I get it - support questions aren't as much fun as crazy new feature requests or scintillating discussions... They're still important though.

As with #2... If we don't hold up our end of the bargain, this has to go back off. (Also, I'll be able to provide a definitive answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268779/can-we-make-this-meta-site-work-for-mentoring) and give a hard look at the folks who told me trying to solve this a different way 4 years ago was unnecessary...)

Comment: I am more than willing to try to keep an open mind, be positive and collaborative about this. Hopefully so are the new users who will use this feature.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature-request: If I enter a valid question url, it shows me a template (Do not remove or edit. Questions not about your post will be deleted). If I click on discard it should redirect me back to the enter a link page but it just clears the textarea so that new users might assume that they can now post everything.

Comment: Jumping in at the 13th hour here, so to speak, but if this is still active, the wording could be improved to mention "you may ask a question about your own Stack Overflow post specifically *regardless of your reputation*" (italicized text added).

Comment: I am thoroughly confused as to how anyone reaches this interface. [I'm not the only one.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386392/fix-or-remove-the-broken-i-have-a-question-about-my-stack-overflow-post-featur?cb=1#comment706004_386392) Does it just appear on question pages after the user posts? Is it on Ask a Question after they've asked for the first time? Do they have to come to Meta and press Ask a Question? Some other path to it?

Comment: [/questions/ask](/questions/ask)

Answer (score 9):

On one hand I see the benefit - on the other I foresee the <s>spam</s> significant volume of meta posts from users who don't put in any effort to their questions will create <s>when they see a slightly too convenient link...</s>

Although I'm not opposed to giving it a try - I really hope that the off-switch isn't out of arms reach...

Edit: There is no link. Thank goodness. The risk of traffic increasing is still present though, so I still think the off switch should still be handy. But it shouldn't be as likely to be a problem as I first feared.

Comment: As the question points out, there is no link: "users are only shown this feature if they come here and attempt to ask a question here".

Comment: That makes me feel much more at ease. I'm not sure where that idea came from now. The risk is still there though, so my answer is not completely irrelevant so I don't think I'll delete it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you see the top answer to the discussion post linked in the question?

Comment: All good points in that post. SO being bigger would of course attract more posts, but it is certainly true that most effort-free users won't bother to look for meta.

Comment: The biggest risk is to the people using the feature. It's not all that discoverable, so those using it will have put in some effort already, but *Meta is Murder*, and I don't think it'll be a good experience for those that use it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do note that we get a lot of people who go ask about their question on Meta Stack Exchange, who end up with an even worse experience because their query is (rightfully) marked as "off-topic" and they are told to post here. Trouble is, they can't, so they're left pretty stuck. This is what the feature was intended to address. The original plan was to implement it on all sites once it was confirmed to be non-disruptive on sites with lower traffic, but the plan fell through for some reason.

Comment: @gparyani: I'm aware. I'm just pointing out that there is a risk to those that ask about their post, too.

Comment: @gparyani: as for the risk that we get flooded with bad 'fix my question' or 'plesae upovte my query' questions here on Meta when this feature is enabled, given that we already have plenty of misdirected questions being posted here on Meta, I know I can trust this community to deal with such posts swiftly (closing, downvoting, educating the poster in comments). I don't think it'll be much of an additional burden.

Comment: @gparyani: last but not least: please edit your question to make it clear that such < 5 rep users are currently seeking out Meta.SE instead to post these questions, that's helpful to know in this discussion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I mentioned that in the linked discussion; will edit that here into this request.

Comment: @MartijnPieters indeed, and I have changed my mind on this issue for that very reason.  I am, however, keeping a note of the ID's of those who supported this measure enthusiasically from the start and, if there are a lot of 'explain' etc. posts from the 1-5'ers, I will be cordially asking that those users handle them:)

Answer (score 0):

Over the last few months I’ve been collecting some data: finding questions that don’t use this feature properly and taking screenshots of them. I was specifically looking for this feature being misused, i.e. either OPs asking *nothing* after the default “I have a question about my Stack Overflow post ⟨link⟩”, or basically reposting the original question.

Since I cannot search deleted posts, my data set on misused questions is not complete, and since the default phrase can be edited, [searching `"I have a question about my Stack Overflow post"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I+have+a+question+about+my+Stack+Overflow+post%22) may also not produce a complete list of non-deleted questions.

Having said that, with the available data, I’m presenting some statistics on questions that aren’t deleted and don’t misuse the feature, as well as questions that are deleted and clearly misuse the feature.

### Non-deleted questions not misusing the feature

Using the search above, there are currently 25 non-deleted questions containing that phrase. Of those, only 12 are well-received (score > 0). The average score is −6.28.

### Deleted questions misusing the feature

This is a list of links to such questions, their IDs, and screenshots. That’s 37 questions.

- [370934](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370934) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsUL0.png))
- [371685](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371685) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62nw8.png))
- [372191](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372191) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qTEL.png))
- [373007](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373007) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABkJW.png))
- [373378](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373378) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPt6O.png))
- [373523](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373523) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdZWM.png))
- [374365](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374365) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43AIG.png))
- [374409](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374409) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msRC8.png))
- [374899](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374899) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWRbd.png))
- [375355](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375355) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl6Aj.png))
- [376170](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376170) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1f2l.png))
- [376501](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376501) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fbjg.png))
- [376609](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376609) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yFHK.png))
- [376615](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376615) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U8Ob.png))
- [377138](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377138) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3YNx.png))
- [377140](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377140) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hqZ.png))
- [377710](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377710) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA2Dg.png))
- [377909](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377909) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWdZ3.png))
- [378704](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378704) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e0hN.png))
- [379220](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379220) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2tPm.png))
- [379842](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379842) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROtmf.png))
- [380099](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380099) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6PJO.png))
- [380191](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380191) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb1rv.png))
- [380438](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380438) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNWTo.png))
- [380529](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380529) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH3PO.png))
- [380576](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380576) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blJNE.png))
- [380945](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380945) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHjrx.png))
- [381076](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381076) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IegAn.png))
- [381267](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381267) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5OQN.png))
- [381363](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381363) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHpBn.png))
- [381983](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381983) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUy1n.png))
- [382011](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382011) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F7f7.png))
- [382507](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382507) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKYyn.png))
- [382528](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382528) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0tGI.png))
- [382552](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382552) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruN31.png))
- [382625](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382625) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZUgn.png))
- [384194](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384194) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f65b3.png))

---

Here’s all these statistics in a pie-chart:

[image: 19.35% well-received, 20.97% non-deleted, not well-received, 59.68% deleted]

Looks pretty bad.

Most of the negatively scored questions complain about downvotes or lack of attention. 17 of the 25 OPs of the non-deleted questions have already reached the privilege to ask on Meta, usually very soon after asking, but of course, this isn’t accounting for the Meta effect.

So, are almost 60% of deleted questions and less than 20% of questions actually engaging in valuable discussion enough to disable this feature again? If not, what are the thresholds? In terms of the ratio of misuse over total use, this seems to be happening very frequently; or are we waiting for the feature to be used improperly a specific number of times over a specific period of time?

If there’s someone who can search for deleted posts, maybe more data can be provided.

Comment: Even if you take into account the fact that your data may not be complete, that's still very few uses of the system (approximately 100 overall uses here, compared to the 7,000+ *daily* questions on the main site). While it may be true that the majority of them are deleted, it's still an extremely low volume, enough to be dealt with by moderation. If, on the other hand, this were overwhelming this site with thousands of said questions, I'd agree.

Comment: @gparyani So we keep this feature enabled until it gets misused too many times per day (or month, etc.)? It still feels strange that we keep this feature enabled that produces _more low-quality and off-topic_ posts.

Comment: The data you assembled is useful; my take on it, however, is contrary to yours. Sixty-two extra questions over a year amounts to a barely noticeable increase of Meta's moderation workload. It is a very reasonable cost for upwards of twelve productive Meta Q&As to take place.

Comment: @SebastianSimon You're basing things on *potential future* gains. If it actually starts to get high, then notify me again, but there doesn't seem to be any evidence of a steady rise.

Comment: At least one of the positively scored meta questions also resulted in the score of the main site question going from negative to positive and prevented two bad edits. In the cases where the OP actually asks a question, the result seems to be better content.