# Is it required to react quickly to an answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Gnat Programming System: Install gdb version 8.0.1 in parallel with GPS 2018 to sign gdb code. Experiences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000208/gnat-programming-system-install-gdb-version-8-0-1-in-parallel-with-gps-2018-to)

The answer to my question seems very helpful. But I will not be able to try out the advice myself within the next two weeks. Should I add a corresponding comment because it might be considered impolite not to react immediately?

Comment: I would suggest that 1) you give the answer an up-vote if is helpful, and 2) yes, comment to the poster if you feel that it may be a while before you can get back regarding the answer's correctness. This would be quite considerate of you to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how would OP know if it's helpful if he's unable to verify that it solves the issue expresed in the question?

Comment: @Braiam true which is why my comment above has an if block within it, in RPN  ;)

Comment: How did you manage to ask this question? I thought the [participate in Meta privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) is awarded at 5 reputation.

Comment: Don't ask technical questions on technical sites if you can't interact with the answerer almost immediately. A two-week delay is ludicrous.

Comment: @DonaldDuck [Enable the "ask about own post" feature for low-rep users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/enable-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-for-low-rep-users)

Comment: 1. you are allowed to ask on Meta if it is specifically related to your original question

Comment: 2. Sometimes, in real life, obstacles get in your way, like work load, sick children, hurricanes, that keep you from answering a question (or was that irony in the comment from Neill Butterworth?) I better stop here...

Answer (score 5):

Required, no. Useful to you, the asker, yes.

Ok, that makes no sense, right? Well, the thing about acknowledgement is that the answerer would have feedback, such that it wouldn't be wondering if the post was even seen. Second, reading and reacting to the answer could make you preemptively aware of potential issues that the answer has, like inapplicability to your context.

While some answerers just fire and forget, others try to hang around looking for issues in their own or other answers, so informing all the answerers that you are temporarily unable to verify that the proposed solution solves the issue, allow them to focusing on other problems and leaving that aside, for now.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not required of you to react quickly to an answer, but a clarifying comment could be welcome to some people if you feel like it.

---

There are, in theory, absolutely no requirements for you to take any action quickly about that answer, be it upvote (when one has the possibility to), accept, or comment to ask clarifications.

In practice, after lengthy periods of time, some people might think you'll never come around, so they'll act anywhere from not caring to revenge downvoting to deleting their answer.

These reactions are arguably rare however, and most people are not so reckless.

Comment: I sometimes wonder if pre-emptively warning about things such as revenge voting is really a good idea. That's like warning everyone that gets into a car with you that you might get into an accident caused by someone else... it puts unnecessary fear out there, chances are greater it won't happen. But if it does happen it hits extra hard, try to explain away that something predicted and then happening is only random chance.

Comment: People do complain about users ghosting after they get an answer but revenge down votes due to not getting an up vote would be incredibly, shockingly petty.