# Fix or remove the useless 'I have a question about my Stack Overflow post' template feature

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, meta

At some point in the past, a feature was introduced that points SO users to MSO when they have a question about their post. You can recognise them by the following text:

> I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: <post link>

Here's a screenshot of a recent case, if you don't know what this is about:

[image]

Users are supposed to further clarify what question they have about their SO post, but the majority of these consist of nothing more than the template text. Often these MSO questions are quickly downvoted and closed, and if a voter is feeling generous they'll add a comment to the MSO question explaining what is wrong.

So what is the result of such questions:

- the OP is not helped with their SO question
- the OP is introduced to MSO in a rather unpleasant way
- other MSO users sigh upon seeing the umpteenth case of this issue

Please, either fix this feature or just remove it altogether.

Comment: Note that this _feature_ was created to let users with 1 rep ask a question on MSO. Do you propose we don't give 1 rep users the opportunity to ask here at all, or do you want to allow them to ask without the constraint of having to link their post? _Please fix_ also seems rather undefined.

Comment: @ErikA I'd like to be less vague than "fix it" but to be honest I still don't know exactly what the goal of this feature is. I've tried finding an announcement post multiple times but failed to do so. Preferably something is done to better guide users while using the feature, but it does more harm than good by leaving it in its current state.

Comment: The idea behind the feature, as I believe it, is to allow 1-rep users to ask things about a specific question (such as _why was this closed_) without giving them full meta privileges, to avoid them just asking their question here (which often happens with low-rep users that do have the meta privilege). It's only exposed to users without the _participate on meta_ privilege (<5 rep).

Comment: I think it's good to give news users this capability, and I know I've seen some of them use it properly.  Everybody can be confused their first time on the site and have no idea why it's not getting a good reception.  That said, my feeling is that I encounter far more boilerplate usages than useful ones.  It might be worth digging into some stats to see how many actually use it correctly, and see if the value is there.

Comment: Afaik there's a fair amount of guidance, but misusing this feature is often a desperation move (I really need an answer but don't have enough rep for a bounty, and stuff on meta gets attention), which also shows by them often adding things like _please give answer_ to the post. No amount of guidance can protect from knowingly misusing a feature out of desperation.

Comment: I'm ambivalent. Yes, my recollection is that almost all uses of this feature have been both unproductive and probably unpleasant for the asker; but would love to see some stats about the use of this feature and whatever impact it had so far.

Comment: Oh, and btw, [33 non-deleted posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1069181) since others sometimes edit out that template stuff as noise, as they probably should.

Comment: @Stijn [This is the \[feature-request\] Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366603/2751851), which includes [Shog's answer green-lighting it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366734/2751851), and [an answer with stats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384216/2751851). Personally, I think the feature should stay: the volume of questions asked in this manner is low enough that enabling some of those users to post a relevant Meta question is still a net gain.

Comment: I need to say that this feature isn't broken - it's working perfectly fine. The problem is that it's being abused, and while that needs to be addressed, there was always a chance this would happen, and I highly doubt it they knew about it and still implemented it if they thought the benefits didn't outweigh the downsides.

Comment: Is it really a big surprise that the people who post low-quality content on the main site, in spite of all the provided guidance, are also posting low-quality content on Meta? This is provided as an escape hatch, an escalation system for that rare case where a competent, conscientious user gets caught off guard and needs our support. There’s no real way to “fix” it. Other than, perhaps, make the garbage easier to clean up. To be fair, though, I think you are massively overstating the scale of the problem. I monitor Meta quite closely, and I don’t see these questions all that frequently.

Comment: @CodyGray People who post low-quality content on the main site are unlikely to discover the meta site in the first place. This is evidenced by the low overall number of uses of this feature (only a few dozen in the entire life of the feature), compared to the thousands of low-quality questions *per day*.

Comment: That is certainly true, @gparyani, but I don't see how it disagrees with anything that I wrote.

Comment: *Where* is this feature you're talking about? Is it part of the template? Sitting on Ask a Question? Just a random link on every page? I have no idea to what you're referring from your question alone.

Comment: Also, I can't figure out how the user reaches that interface from Shog's post. I'm probably missing something in the Q/A there, but it's just not sticking out at me.

Comment: @jpmc26 according to Erik A's comment: *"It's only exposed to users without the participate on meta privilege (<5 rep)."*

Comment: Okay, but where is it exposed? Is it just sitting on their question page after they ask it kind of like the "Add a comment" link/button/thing? Does it show up in Ask a Question? I'm just really confused about how anyone would see it.

Comment: @jpmc26 I honestly don't know, I'd have to create a sock puppet account to figure out the details.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Sorry for all the back and forth. At least I'm not the only one in the dark.

Comment: @Stijn It's the /questions/ask page for new users (<5 rep).

Comment: @CodyGray perhaps we can auto-tag them with something. So its clear this came through that form, and (the biggest gain) it makes it easier to curate.

Answer (score 42):

It's not broken.  It's *misused* on occasion.

That is to say, someone will use this feature and post on Meta to either:

- bring attention to their question, or
- ask why their question is getting downvoted.

The former is the wrong use case; we don't want them posting about their question to get attention for it.  It's a double-edged sword, anyway.  The latter is *better*, but the OP has to be coached into how to actually ask about their question and seek constructive criticism for it.  The issue is that someone sees an empty form and decides to ask *whatever* in it, which is a missing guard rail in this context.

The tool itself is *fine*.  Education around it is what's likely lacking.

Comment: Maybe those post need an Meta Ask Question Wizard ...

Comment: @rene you jest, but...

Comment: .... in 6 to 8 weeks @Stijn

Answer (score 23):

I don't think the feature should be removed. [An answer to the relevant [feature-request] Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384216/2751851) includes some data about questions asked through it. In a span of about nine months, 62 questions were asked, with 12 of them having been well-received. While that might look like a low signal-to-noise ratio, the volume of such questions is very low (less than two questions a week). That being so, the minute increase to the Meta workload thus incurred is a fair cost for making it possible for the good questions among those to exist.

As for giving new users misusing the feature a rough welcome: that is a valid point; however, for a new asker who misuses the feature by posting the unedited template text, having their blatantly inappropriate Meta post closed is probably the least of their problems ([as Erik A notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386392/fix-or-remove-the-broken-i-have-a-question-about-my-stack-overflow-post-featur/386396#comment705628_386392), "no amount of guidance can protect from knowingly misusing a feature out of desperation"). In any case, it shouldn't take "a voter [feeling] generous" for a comment pointing out the misuse to be left -- that should rather be the standard procedure.

Answer (score 21):

Deferring this, because while there's certainly room for improvement it's not exactly a flood. [When I enabled this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/enable-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-for-low-rep-users/366734#366734), my big concern was that the huge amount of traffic on SO would translate to a huge amount of traffic to meta... That didn't happen; we get maybe one of these questions every couple days on average.

As Cody said, it's there as an option for the rare case when it's needed, and isn't causing much harm outside of that.

Comment: What do you think of the proposal in my answer below, to exclude the default template text when calculating the question's quality score, so that questions with just barely more than that get blocked as not meeting quality standards?

Comment: Lotta work for almost no gain. Could accomplish the same thing with a regex, or even just increasing the minimum post length. Offers zero help for the majority of folks who get into trouble here; the answers suggesting better guidance for askers are on the right track.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps a specially designed closure message for these occurrences would be an ideal solution? I say this because the keyword of Stack Overflow in 2019 is "Welcoming", so a new user getting a flurry of downvotes and their question on the main site, then using this feature in a rather poor/not the intended way to have the process repeated on Meta too would not be very welcoming.

Yes the closure message is "Unclear what you're asking" and we all know it is unclear but maybe it can be more specific to the situation as it is pretty obvious when someone is using this feature (<5 rep or it contains some text along the lines of "I have a question about my Stack Overflow post).

The message could be something like (my rather poor attempt)

> Here on Meta Stack Overflow we do not answer technical questions, we answer questions about the Main site e.g. The workings or questions themselves. Please provide more clarification on what question you have about your Stack Overflow question such as why was it downvoted/closed? and/or how can I improve it to meet our quality standards?

This could also have some links to the help centre like the current unclear closure message (e.g. the How to ask page) and the What's Meta page.

I think this could be useful is it gives them an insight as to why it was closed without the need for clicking the help links (which I think we all know most people don't open them).

Comment: I think this suggestion speaks to what I feel is the heart of the problem: SO, and other SE sites in general, do an extremely bad job of introducing new users to our systems, and that is what leads to these issues.  I believe that if we did better at setting user expectations up front, prior to them even asking their first question, they'd get a way better reception, for the most part.

Answer (score 5):

I think this feature should remain enabled.

As duplode said in their answer, the workload is low enough to be dealt with by moderation: over the lifetime of the feature, only a few dozen such questions have been asked overall on this site, compared to the thousands of *daily* questions asked on the main site. Part of this is because this feature isn't advertised anywhere on the main site; users only find out about it if they somehow wander here or they are linked to this site in, say, a comment. I think it's worth taking in a *few* extra questions to give new users the ability to find out more information about their own posts.

Also, it's worth pointing out that before this feature was enabled, we used to get a lot of people asking questions about their Stack Overflow posts over on Meta Stack Exchange, from where they'd need to be migrated over to this site. Community members can't migrate questions from Meta Stack Exchange, only moderators can, and having this feature enabled has reduced the workload on moderators there having to migrate these questions; the number of questions migrated from there to here has decreased measurably since this feature was enabled here.

You do raise a valid point, however:

> the majority of these consist of nothing more than the template text

Why not modify the minimum quality filter, so that the default template text is excluded when calculating the quality score, and any questions submitted with barely more than this template text will be [blocked as not meeting quality standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar)? It's also worth mentioning that I [proposed a similar thing for Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327721/377214) for a similar template text issue.

(For full transparency, I'm the one who [proposed enabling this feature here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366603/2751851).)

Comment: I don't think we got *that* many users.  This feature can be used by 1-rep users, so at a minimum before we got substantially *fewer*.