# Create a special mod flag for new users when their post is put on hold, deleted or heavily downvoted

Tags: discussion, flags, new-users, user-interface, quality-improvement

The reception on meta for some new user's posts about poor posts on main are not always well received. Possibly due in part to the new user not understanding how to use the site and also due to impatience (in part brought about by fatigue) of regular users on the site.

Can we have  special flag option for new users, it could be triggered by the same heuristics that trigger the new user icon (if that's not too unrelated in the code base)?  A flag asking for a post review if the post is deleted or put on hold. It could also be a lifeline for new users who are being heavily downvoted and need the brakes on. A mod can always temporarily delete or lock a post and work through the issues with the user.

This may take away some of the angst for genuine users wanting to improve their contributions from being lost on the site.

Yes, it does put more pressure on moderators, but there's been a clear shift in the moderation team in wanting to reach out to new users and help them.

It is something that could be refined down the track if the moderator team felt overloaded, farmed out to willing regulars or we could recruit more moderators.

In the meantime, would it be too difficult to provide new users with something like this?

Comment: Can't new users, without the rep, go to Meta for the "I have a question about my post" part? I dunno how it's presented, but they *do* have that. Now..... I don't think it's enough... but that's still relevant I'd say

Comment: @Patrice not without 5 rep. Also the posts are not always well received, so it may take the heat off the new user and put the responsibility off the community - to give people a break on meta and the new user a better chance of succeeding. I could be talking through my hat... :-{ time will tell.

Comment: I mean for main posts - not meta posts - but we could include those I guess. *can of worms opening*

Comment: @Patrice they can, yeah (unless it's been recently disabled). IIRC, teams customers can go on meta without any rep or any posts.

Comment: @Yvette no no I'm with you 100% here. I was just asking to clarify that piece. I thought that you could come to meta WITHOUT that 5, with the "I have a question about my question". I'm not saying it's enough. I just wanted to be sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: @Patrice not if the help centre is to be believed :\

Comment: Any user can ask on Meta with a link to a specific post, no reputation required: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274518/a-way-for-new-users-to-ask-about-their-post-specifically

Comment: @yivi it's to help post quality - hm should add that tag

Comment: @Yvette https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366603/enable-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-for-low-rep-users no no, it can be done :). I dunno if it's the right answer to the problem though, so your FR may still be needed :)

Comment: @animuson hmm ok. something new I learned

Comment: @Patrice *"we have to actually welcome those meta-questions"* hmmm....

Comment: @Nick and that's why I'm saying "I dunno if it's the right answer to the problem"...

Comment: I wonder if new users are aware they can do that. Patrice and I didn't know and Patrice has been here for years and I'm a mod... hmm

Comment: @Yvette I guess it depends on how it's presented to newbies. Maybe a special view on a downvoted/poorly received question? If that's how it's shown, it may help. Unsure.

Comment: Perhaps more specific _my question was received poorly, what do I do now?_ guidance could be better suited for this, including an example of how to ask about it on meta (e.g. not _why was this downvoted + link_, but _how do I improve this question/ask this_). I fear directing these to the mods will lead to trouble, we've already seen some disagreement to veteran curators and specific mods about close votes and they'll be put in the position to overrule curators more often.

Comment: Is there enough moderator time to handle to (potentially) large volume of new user flags? I guess these cases will not be done in a few seconds. Another problem I see is that moderators do not cover all topics: How will questions get handled in areas where no mod with that knowledge exists?

Comment: Wouldn't these types of users be caught in the "first posts" queue? I don't know if it'd be too late by then though.

Comment: This sounds like you want to roll the First Posts queue into the mod flag queue. Is that about right?

Comment: One thing I didn't think about is volume. How much additional work does this potentially put on moderators?

Comment: @Zoe I'm really not sure, it could be a trial  I guess

Comment: Is it a common occurrence that new users, who listen to feedback, are downvoted into oblivion?

Answer (score 28):

I believe this would be better handled by bringing back (after finishing its implementation) the [mentorship program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project).

There are plenty of new users with badly received questions in need of guidance, and there are more users willing to help than the users in the pool of moderators, and helping other users to polish their questions (when possible) doesn't need nor necessarily benefit from receiving it from a user with a diamond.

We do already have a couple of queues for this type of thing ("First Posts", "Late Answers", and "Help & Improvement"; at the very least); and if they are not working as they should I believe it would be preferable to retool these queues and create new tools powered by all the community, rather to charge our relentless exception handlers with yet another responsibility.

Comment: Yep or being put somewhere there's experienced users who are feeling patient enough to work with people new to the site. We all have our days. Maybe enrol to review that queue?

Comment: Mentorship needs to be a two way street.  We need users here who are patient enough to help guide new users, absolutely.  But we also need new users who are open to being guided; the system should be opt-in for new users, so mentors aren't trying to help someone who doesn't care.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Are moderators limited in the amount of review tasks they can take on the review queues? Because nothing stops a diamond from spending more type in the queues I mentioned, right?

Comment: I suppose the only drawback of this is it doesn't satisfy the immediate "Help! My question is in trouble, what do I do?" need that some users face when their early questions are bombing and they feel like there's nothing they can do about it. Having something they can actually click (read: do) would probably alleviate a lot of the anxiety. As a long-term solution though, this works.

Comment: @yivi no, we're not limited.. I think this has turned out to be a good question - as a brainstorm

Comment: Also, I believe your idea would be better suited to meta, since meta already serves a support role and sometimes the meta hounds are _hasty_ in moderating questions here. There is less traffic and much more voting. Maybe an auto-flag for these would be more useful, since it would alert the mod for someone who _might_ be actively looking for help, and failing to get it.

Comment: I will note as some [experienced users are still boycotting the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented/385143#385143) they may not be as helpful as they once were for helping users find & improve questions (or maybe moreso as most of the time I just downvoted and moved on so auto-delete would happen)

Comment: @LinkBerest yeh, I don't think another review queue is the answer tbh

Answer (score 21):

Based on what's happened on Meta over the last, say 48 hours, I can see why this is coming about.

However, I can say with absolute confidence that this would be a *bad* idea.

The issue is simpler than you seem to be willing to accept - there are people who *want* to participate on the site and want to learn why their contribution(s) are not well received, and then there are those who *don't* want to.

We should focus our efforts and energy on the people who really *do* want to participate.  While they're not going to be as vociferous as their counterparts, they're the ones who will more readily receive our guidance.

Comment: While I'm not sure I get the bit about the previous 48hs, this touches on a bit I didn't address on my answer: an _"auto"_ flag is bad because it is raised even when the post owner will not be necessarily be responsive to helping efforts. The post owner needs to have agency on something like this (be it handled by moderators or anyone else), or more often than not it can be a major waste of misdirected efforts.

Comment: @yivi:  There was a bit of a flare-up on Meta.  I think the OP deleted the original post they were upset about and then made an effort to leave.  The effort was to keep that person around since a moderator felt like that decision was in haste, but it didn't quite...work...mostly for the circumstance I display above.

Comment: Oh, **that** one. Thanks for the context.

Comment: Haven't there been 3 major incidents in the past couple of days? (as in users - not necessarily posts). This isn't usually meta, but if this is what it risks becoming full-time, I have to agree with Makoto. If the mentorship system is implemented, and *that* is the way an unnecessarily large amount of users react in some or another form, then this is the better option.

Comment: @Zoe "3 major incidents"  - you make it sound like war in the Middle East, not just a website that takes itself far too seriously.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "major incidents" is used in a lot of different contexts, not just  wars in real life

Comment: @Zoe hyperbole is rarely useful.

Comment: ...and somehow a metaphor comparing this to a war *was*...