# Why doesn't the system prevent repeating the exact same question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, post-notice

Here is one example among many I face regularly<sup>1</sup>: [Decrease opacity of images which are not highlighted (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61123007/8620333)

As we can clearly see, the OP is repeating the same question because the duplicate wasn't suitable for him. I will not discuss if the duplicate is correct; my question is: Why is he allowed to repost the same question? Why can't the system detect such an *easy* copy/paste and prevent it?

<sup>1</sup>It's worth noting that I started seeing this behavior a lot since [the new post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide), for sure, due to the fact that in the banner the site encourages people to ask a new question and [the feature-request to disable this was declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339734/386331).

If we cannot change the banner, can't we at least add more restriction/tests to prevent repeating the same question?

In the example I gave, the old question is still visible, but in most of the cases, the OP simply deletes his question and then repposts it. It's a bit annoying because I have to watch the same user for a while in order to close his question again and again and I end up with a lot of *"friendly and welcoming"* comments.

I will highlight one comment from that question to show how the system is handling this poorly:

> [image]

**UPDATE**

And here is another comment:

> [image]

This is really annoying and make duplicate closure useless...

**UPDATE 2**

And yet another example of someone posting *exactly* the same question after 2h from posting the first one and the first one wasn't even closed (check the edit history to notice the copy/paste)

1st: [How do you hide that floating scroll indicator thing on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62098331/8620333)

2nd: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62099409/8620333

**UPDATE 3**

Another example of repeated question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/62180410/8620333

[div content editable with placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62175319/8620333)

**UPDATE 4**

And another one:

[footer do not go at the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62364887/8620333)

[Footer do not automatically position itself beneath the content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62369282/8620333)

**UPDATE 5**

> [image]

**UPDATE 6**

Another annoying example where the OP reposted the same question after only few minutes:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/62855535/8620333

> [image]

**UPDATE 7**

Another *perfect* copy/past (only the title was changed). The initial question wasn't even closed:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/62934098/8620333

[Scaling a transformation based on window size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62864144/8620333)

**UODATE 8**

> [image]

**UPDATE 9**

> [image]

**UPDATE 10**

> [image]

Comment: Isn't it obvious, there's a (2) at the end of the title, totally different question

Comment: @Nick yes like the suffix Windows add to file name when you copy them in the same location -.- ... let's hope we won't have the (3)

Comment: Simple, because Stack Exchange Inc. doesn't want questions closed, because questions create page views, which (supposedly) create revenue. IMO, moderators should respond to users who do this by destroying the latters' accounts so that they can never post again.

Comment: @IanKemp it's a bit harsh to punish the users for what SE is pushing them to do.

Comment: @VLAZ I agree, but what other options do we have? :(

Comment: @IanKemp not many, that's to be sure. It's either closing the questions and explain why until they understand or...until they get question banned. Not ideal either way. SE has been in a more cooperative mood lately, so it's *possible* they listen this time and do something about it. Or...you know, not but that hardly changes how things stand anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ I can confirm that they don't (and won't understand). Even worse, they are convinced that I am the one who is breaking the rules by not allowing them to repeat their question and I am the bad guy making SO the worst place ever. I cannot give you examples because I automatically flag those *welcoming comments*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I'm aware how users react to duplicate closures. And you are doing an *amazing* job alongside so many gold badge holders. Yet, that's really where we're at - SE is pushing people to re-ask questions. We've tried to point out that's not correct to both curators and question askers. Yet nothing happened. So far at least twice, if I remember correctly. SE is throwing curator under the bus here and nowadays trying to save its image by trying to reduce "toxicity" yet said "toxicity" is in no small part driven by SE decisions in the first place.

Comment: There are a couple related posts that I’m linking here to find them more easily:
[“You can edit the question or post a new one”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394552/4642212),
[Add a statement about re-opening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339731/289905),
[How could we improve our planned post notice improvements?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332500/289905),
[New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337015/289905).

Comment: But [hallway usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/) (or the equivalent virtual version) should have caught it(?)

Comment: Regarding your Update 2: yes, the second question includes a copy of the first question, but these questions aren’t the _exact_ same. The first question asks how to hide a thing, the second one asks what that thing is called. This could be resolved by editing the second question, remove the copy and don’t make the second question depend on the first so much (because it really doesn’t depend on it). These questions aren’t real duplicates of one another.

Comment: @user4642212 they are asking the same. The second question is saying *I want to hide that element* which is what asked in the first question. Also check the new screenshot he added. He's showing the exact same element --> The user is asking the same thing but adding more clarification so he should edit his old question instead of asking a new one

Comment: @user4642212 and by *exactly* the same I don't mean a string comparaison but exactly the same purpose/issue. The user want to hide an element and he simply don't know how or what is this element. It's clear if we read both question and it's also clear since both of them are asked within 2h.

Comment: _“and by exactly the same I don't mean a string comparaison but exactly the same purpose/issue”_ — then how does this relate to the title of the question _“Why doesn't the system prevent repeating the ‘exact’ same question?”_? How can _the system_ recognize the same “purpose/issue” if not via string comparison?

Comment: @user4642212 you have edited both questions so I am arguing that both are still the same even without the same text. Now it's irrelevant to this question after your edits but before your edits the user is doing a simple copy/past which is not good and is an indicator of repeating the same question

Comment: Will this question eventually grow into a large collection of links like my [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384216/4642212) that shows that around 60 % of Meta questions by <5-rep-users of the format _“I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [link]”_ are deleted and only around 20 % are well received? My post sits at −1 and I don’t think that feature was disabled or anything else has been done about it.

Comment: The reason the user asked a new question is that he probably looked at all the questions similar to his own, and couldn't find anything.

Comment: And the next example: [How to add avariable to a part of website address / href?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62683766/4642212) → [How do you add a variable as part of a website address in Javasript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62685023/4642212).

Comment: Maybe it'd help if the closed post notice made it clear that "ask a new question" does *not* mean to ask the same question again.

Comment: Somewhat related: [User asked four similar questions within fourteen hours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402390/user-asked-four-similar-questions-within-fourteen-hours/402396#402396)

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511288/how-to-get-the-occurence-of-trigram-in-text-data#comment115837680_65511288

Comment: Each time you update this question to include a new example, I want to upvote it once again...

Comment: when colleagues ask me what StackOverflow is, I send them here