# Why doesn't the system detect user copying other answers?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, duplicate-answers

It's again me complaining about copy/paste after this one: *[Why doesn't the system prevent repeating the "exact" same question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396474/why-doesnt-the-system-prevent-repeating-the-exact-same-question)*.

This time it's about users simply copying existing answers. A trivial copy/paste that IMHO a system can easily identify, but unfortunately nothing is done and such an answer gather upvotes for doing the copy/paste.

I know I can flag such answers and my flag are always useful (the answers are deleted), but I also know that moderators get notified when a user repeat the same answers. I guess it would be good if we can scale the algorithm to consider more cases. Of course, it's not easy to test all the answers and compare them with all the others, but with some heuristics we can identify many of them.

Recent examples among many I usually find:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231074/8620333 (not yet flagged)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62126829/8620333 (already deleted)

Both are explicitly referencing another answer so the link is there and the text is exactly the same. In such cases, an automatic system can easily follow the link to clearly identify the copy/paste. We can also send a notification to the user explaining that this not the correct way to answer and better flag as duplicate.

It's also easy to find if we do a simple search query with a few words.

For example [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22The+value+of+said+property+is+adjusted+automatically+according%22) will lead us to three answers where two are identical. This is what I always do when I smell a plagiarism. I google some content and bingo! I get the source.

I think the system can easily grab a random sentence from an answer (long enough to make sure it's unique) then search for it inside SO and see if there is a matching. With such a process we can easily identify the above cases and it won't cost a lot in development.

Comment: Never trusted those "diamonds". Plagiarists, that is what they are ...

Comment: I assumed a naive SEDE query would be useless but [who could have guessed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1249563) ...

Comment: @rene oh that's nice! I have a good list of question to close now. It also confirms that the system can easily do this.

Comment: And here is a version that also does answers in the selected tag: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1249564?tagname=css

Comment: @rene "diamonds" will hate you for giving them *more* works ;) now we have to clean your query in all the tags!

Comment: Only 63 exact duplicate questions? I expected more of them.

Comment: @BDL it are EXACT dupes, as in javascript === exact.

Comment: No, worries. I'm hated already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969175/why-does-widthauto-behave-differently-than-heightauto#36969324 Turns out the user who made the original answer refers to it later on.

Comment: @Jonathan this is ok, I do this all the time. After all it's his answer and he can refer to it in order to avoid repeating a same explanation.

Comment: @rene we should create a curators support group, 'Closers Corner', maybe...

Comment: @MartinJames I am not sure if you are joking, but there is SOCVR chatroom already. However, we do not allow old requests there.

Comment: @rene: Can you add a (short) description to the SEDE queries?

Comment: @rene: [Doug Crockford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook&t=15m0s)? Don't you mean ...`==`...?

Comment: @Martin James: Or ['Plagiarism Busters'](https://www.newsweek.com/its-bird-its-plane-its-plagiarism-buster-147537)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm still utterly confused by them. But you might like [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=49426681) and [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49426666#49426666)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I could only add a description to the second SEDE query as that one is linked to my profile. The other one was more of a proof of concept and I didn't bother to login when I started. So that one stays description and title less. On the plus side: no spelling and grammar errors on that one ;)

Comment: @Temani Afif doesn't that imply that the thread should actually be closed as a duplicate, if he can just copy and paste the answer?  As far as automating: how will you detect copy/paste with references, as part of an overall solution?

Comment: @user120242 yes it means that he need to flag as duplicate instead of doing the copy/paste (of course it doesn't imply that the question is a duplicate because the copied answer can be irrelevant or not accurate). For the solution, as I detailed in my question: the system can grab a random sentence from the answer before it's posted and try to see if there is a matching inside SO This will identify many plagiarism, not all of them but a good amount of them which is already good. A notification can then be sent to moderator so they can confirm if yes or no it's a plagiarism.

Comment: @TemaniAfif wait, flag?  aren't we supposed to just vote to close them, since that's what voting to close is there for?  even if I had the privs to direct close, I'd prefer voting first.  innocent until proven guilty, wisdom of the collective, alike

Comment: @user120242 it depends on your Rep, the user who did the copy/paste can only flag, still not enough Rep to cast a close vote

Comment: Well, you could always turn this into a feature request.