# User asked four similar questions within fourteen hours

Tags: discussion, similar-questions

A user has asked four very similar questions:

- [my js code for a quiz is not taking in arrays in question tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537960/my-js-code-for-a-quiz-is-not-taking-in-arrays-in-question-tag)
- [My quiz is not changing when i press next what do i do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542283/my-quiz-is-not-changing-when-i-press-next-what-do-i-do)
- [code javascript such that innerhtml of answers changes in relation to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549082/code-javascript-such-that-innerhtml-of-answers-changes-in-relation-to-the-questi)
- [the answers have to show up when i press next or in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64550028/the-answers-have-to-show-up-when-i-press-next-or-in-general).

These questions were all asked within a period of roughly fourteen hours. How should I handle this? I've seen questions like these on meta that were asked two years ago, but this is particularly annoying, especially because two of the questions are identical. Would it be possible to remove all questions that are **identical** to another one asked by the same user?

Comment: The real problem there is that, despite being transparently garbage, those questions had answers instead of down and close votes. If the user got a clearer signal they might not keep making the same mistakes.

Comment: I was going to downvote each of the questions but I didn't have enough rep...

Comment: But did you flag to close the question?

Comment: No I'm still a new user so not sure what that means

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts, you have the privilege to do so.

Comment: Okay - can I flag closed questions?

Comment: Yes, but I doubt that is much useful here in this case. Getting questions closed is a priority

Comment: If a user asks the same question twice, you can flag one as a duplicate of the other. As far as flagging closed questions, unless it’s spam, offensive, or needs a diamond moderator to take action on it, you don’t need to.

Comment: @rene Which flag(s) would be appropriate in this case? I've had VLQ flags denied on that kind of question before, so I'm not entirely sure which one to pick.

Comment: @Clockwork this doesn't mean the question is low quality, as BSMP said, flag the latest one as duplicate of the first. I also add a comment indicating the user asked the same question with a link so other users will be aware of that and that high-rep users will close it faster

Comment: Don't flag the Questions as "Very Low Quality". The flag means: Harmful, delete it now. It's basically useless and it's *not* a close flag. Flag as "needs improvement" → whatever fits :) The "needs improvement" is code for "Should be closed". Picking "duplicate" and choosing any of the other 3 as a target seems a good choice here.

Comment: Anecdotally, this has been my experience with the `pandas` tag more and more

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's not uncommon in the "friendly" tags like [tag:javascript], [tag:php] and [tag:c#]. It's no co-incidence that regulars' rep is so incredibly high in those tags.

Comment: At least the asker was using the javascript snippets correctly. Mind you, that's a lot easier to do with javascript that it is with C code.

Comment: @Scratte The same dialog has similar-sounding options for similar use cases that sends the post to very different (and incompatible) places without any clear indication of this. I'm sure that's not at all confusing nor error-prone for less experienced users... This is especially confusing because many of the posts that need to be closed do not "need improvement", but rather has severe content problems and are unlikely to be salvageable through editing (which kind of sounds familiar...).

Comment: @jonrsharpe please don't use the term "garbage" to refer to other users question. You could use "very low quality" to the same effect. SO has already a problem being really harsh on newcomers, so there's no need to use harsh language as well.

Comment: @Jorjon I appreciate the feedback, but note that you cannot see the content. To quote the first one *"i am a beginner and started like 2 weeks ago i want the question to show in the question field while the question is in array i am not abel to do it help `<code dump>`"*. Another literally contains *"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."*, copy-pasted from the warning that was encouraging the OP to improve their question. I don't think I've been unfair in my classification.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> How should I handle this?

Personally I would:

1. **Flag/close** the newer question(s) as duplicate of the first one from the bunch.
2. **Down-vote** all duplicates and the original if it deserves so.
3. **Leave a comment** with a link to the other question(s) indicating the user is "recycling". It should be phrased in such a way that will both notify other users of the case, and also be constructive to the OP that might not be aware that they are actually doing something wrong (they might think that closed == deleted). Something in the lines of:

   > How is this question different from [this one](<link to question>) you asked some minutes
   > ago? Please don't ask the same question twice. Instead, edit the
   > original question with the missing details. If your edit was good
   > enough, the question will get re-opened and you will get an answer.
4. **If this is a recurring behavior**, i.e. as your example of 4 questions in a short amount of time, or alternatively a few cases of duplicating questions for the same user - use the **moderator flag** to bring the attention to the moderators. Make sure to explain in detail the reason (we don't want to waste their time). They will make sure to explain the situation to the specific user, and suspend or take further steps if deem necessary.

Many new users get frustrated when their question is closed (for whatever reason) so instead of editing the question to be appropriate and maybe re-opened, they just ask a new one, sometimes exactly the same. Sometimes this system works, as other users might answer one of the questions instead of following the above steps so in the end OP will get their answer. Then they will probably keep doing it as it works.

It is therefore important to follow the above steps to make them know this behavior is unacceptable, and possibly direct them to the appropriate help pages for instructions on how to write their questions properly to avoid them getting closed in the first place.

Comment: You can also mod flag this. We typically reach out to them and cover why this isn't allowed.

Comment: @Machavity interesting, didn't know that. I am usually *"afraid"* of mod flags as I know that those should be reserved for some "extreme" cases.

Comment: I'd suggest that if an OP has posted, effectively, the same question 4 times then we're getting to "extreme" circumstances.

Comment: @Larnu agreed. In my answer I tried to be more general and didn't think of that specific case, although it is the subject of the question, so I will edit accordingly

Comment: Perhaps add something about editing (e.g. to what they should be informed about)? Many new users are used to systems where it is impossible to edit anything after posting, and they may not even know it is *possible* to edit.

Answer (score 4):

1. If the question is low quality, it should be treated so (vote to close, vote to delete, VLQ flag, downvote).
2. If the question is essentially the same as the previous one, should be closed as dupe of it.

If the question is essentially the same as the previous question of the OP, he also deserves a warning. In extreme cases some extreme measures might be also considered (by the mods).

However, the VtC/VtD/VLQ/etc rules don't deal with the owner. They only deal with the content.

My opinion about your examples that all of them are crap and their place in the "PostsWithDeleted" table is very well deserved.

The OP should see a very clear and determined behaviour from the System (incl. us): either his posts will follow the site rules, or they will be deleted. Then he will be able to decide, what he wants more.

Comment: Typically, the moderators will warn them the first time. If they continue in the behavior after being warned and offered an explanation by other users, they would then consider a suspension.

Comment: The (VLQ) Very Low Quality flag will be declined on such a post. Also.. any new user will have a hard time understanding your abbreviations: VtC means Vote to Close, VtD means Vote to Delete. Seeing as the Question author seem to be fairly new, and lots of other users see these posts, I think it would be better to spell it out. Not to mention that they can't vote to close, let alone vote to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly spamming the site with the same or very similar questions is [grounds for suspension](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/#:%7E:text=A%20Day%20in%20the%20Penalty%20Box%20Are%20you,severe%20enough%20to%20merit%20outright%20expulsion%20from%20the%E2%80%A6). That being said, I think that it would be appropriate to flag the last 3 as duplicates of the original one, comment explaining why this behavior isn't permitted, and then mod-flag the original one explaining the situation asking them to warn the user not to do that.

Typically this will be sufficient for the user to stop the behavior; however, if they persist in the behavior after being warned and offered an explanation, they should be suspended.