# Someone keeps posting the same bad question again and again

Tags: support, flags

I've already flagged it for mod's attention. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

[Line count inconsistency with spark and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66194678/line-count-inconsistency-with-spark-and-pandas)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183744/using-the-function-of-read-csv-of-spark-and-that-of-pandas-i-get-dataframes-with

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178078/different-rows-count-from-sparkread-and-pandas-read

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66176432/reading-the-same-csv-with-spark-and-pandas-and-finding-differente-rows

Comment: That are two "someone". Maybe students from the same course ...

Comment: or maybe multiple accounts of the same person...

Comment: I've let the other mods know, just in case this keeps going through the evening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the system prevent repeating the exact same question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396474/why-doesnt-the-system-prevent-repeating-the-exact-same-question)

Comment: also : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402656/8620333

Comment: I don't think this question asking what to do about this is a duplicate of an unanswered question asking why the system doesn't prevent it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Someone keeps posting the same bad question again and again

That gets close to abusive. We have a specific flag category for that but that needs context for other flaggers, specially if they can't see deleted posts.

> I've already flagged it for mod's attention.

Awesome. I hope you included links to the other posts so the mods have enough context to understand the actual problem. Posting a bad question isn't forbidden. Deleting the previous bad one and blatantly re-posting is.

> Is there anything else that needs to be done?

If you also close voted and downvoted then your options are exhausted. As an extra measure you could join a chatroom where post moderation is on-topic and leave a [so called cv-pls, del-pls or even flag-pls](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests) message. Room regulars might act on those "*-pls requests" and expedite the closure or deletion of such posts, preventing other community members or visitors spending time on non-value posts.

Before interacting in any chatroom make sure you searched, read and act according to the room rules. Those are often announced or linked to in the room description.