# Why was my question about UAC prompts closed?

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed, needs-more-focus

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Run a Batch File as Admin with no UAC on Another Computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64992474/run-a-batch-file-as-admin-with-no-uac-on-another-computer)

I'm not exactly sure why my question was closed. It says, "needs to be more focused"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Questions that simultaneously show minimal research effort *and* ask for someone else to write a bunch of code for the asker tend to get closed as "needs to be more focused". This close reason is not a perfect fit, but neither are these types of questions a perfect fit for Stack Overflow.

Normally, I try to edit these types of questions into shape and re-open them, but…yours isn't really salvageable. The answer to your question is, "no, absolutely not". It would be a massive security hole in Windows if a batch file could gain administrative privileges *without* going through UAC elevation, so if you *did* figure out a solution, Microsoft would immediately patch it.

Which brings us to another reason why questions are often closed as needing more focus: because they are [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and the question provides no insight about what "X" might be. In other words, you are trying to accomplish thing "X", and you decide that the proper way to accomplish it is to do thing "Y", so you ask about how to achieve thing "Y". Unfortunately, thing "Y" is impossible (or, in other situations, a *really* bad idea), so what you actually should have asked is how to achieve thing "X". Then someone could have helped you. But you didn't; you only told us about thing "Y". So, in order to help you, we'd have to make *assumptions* about what thing "X" might be (and/or ask you in comments). At that point, the question becomes too broad for Stack Overflow, because we cannot deal with underspecified questions that are missing information and require speculation.

Comment: I would have closed/deleted it anyway because of the title translation 'How can I install malware on another computer':(

Comment: Okay, it was a bad idea. I just didn't know why it said, "This post needs to be more focused." No reason to keep downvoting me.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta questions often mean, "I disagree with you". So, in this case, people just thought that your question was correctly closed and should not be reopened. There's no penalty associated with downvotes on Meta sites. Disagreement is allowed. @AnstonSorensen

Comment: I thought it made reputation go down. Also, can this be closed.

Comment: No, nothing on Meta sites affects your reputation. We only close questions because they are off-topic or otherwise unsuitable. This is a perfectly fine question; it doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: @AnstonSorensen - There is no reason to close this question.

Comment: Ah, I see. Somehow I was able to post this, but I can't post another question about another topic because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @AnstonSorensen Your account is not in any way restricted from asking questions on the main site. However, you only have 1 rep on the main site, so you can't ask other questions on Meta. Asking questions on Meta is [a privilege earned at 5 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). You were able to ask this one only because it was support about a specific question of yours; see [this for more details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366734).