# I have a question about my Stack Overflow post

Tags: discussion, questions, meta, faq-proposed

but I forgot to add any details. So now you down, close and delete voted my last hope on any help.

We've all seen those posts. It is this [back alley](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366373/should-the-ask-about-own-post-feature-be-enabled-here-on-stack-overflow) that allows users that lack the reputation to participate on meta yet to post a question about their post on Stack Overflow. But the question template they get doesn't seem overly helpful or is ignored.

Given that these questions can't be answered and should be closed I wonder if we can or need to at least have a single post where we can point those users to in a comment. A bit like we have done with the canonical "require a comment on a downvote". But I don't want to create a dupe target, just an (auto) comment.

I was personally thinking to add an extra answer to [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917) and in that answer provide both guidance and links to the [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and how to find their deleted posts (as those users turn desperate when they are quality-bannned). If those 1-rep posts appear we would leave a friendly comment with a direct link to the to be created answer. I prefer an answer over comment(s) as we can easily evolve/improve the answer as we go.

I invite you to write answers to this very question to argue why we don't need to spend any effort on these mishaps at all or offer a first revision of guidance to be added to the FAQ post. Open for other options as well.

My goal would be to help those few users that are willing to pull themselves out of their misery. With that tailored guidance they can put themselves on the right track.

I do know there is a request to remove or fix this whole template disaster [Fix or remove the useless 'I have a question about my Stack Overflow post' template feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386392) but that is [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) by a CM so it is unlikely to see progress on that in the next 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I almost down, close and delete voted this out of reflex...

Comment: There must be hundreds of similar questions on meta, I made one a month ago, but I am unable to find it now. The rules we created appear to be made to serve a greater purpose. Because the new user coming to seek answers is unable to upvote an answer that they choose, in their context. It's nuts (if you are not a squirrel). So we discard context over a greater good (sadface).

Comment: So @ConradB what info/guidance could have helped you a month ago? You are still fresh in that context, your input is appreciated by me, please post an answer.

Comment: On reading the "back alley" link, I have to wonder that so many people are *finding* the option. It not being easy to find is mentioned in the one answer as a barrier to "everybody" using it. Is it being blogged or something, "out there"? Also, in that discussion is mentioned that, if it's abused, the capability could/should be turned off again for SO. Would you also consider that to be an option? Or having let the genie out of the bottle, the problem is here to stay?

Comment: Actually, I'd favor, when someone tries to use the link, that they're taken directly to the "checklist", without people here needing to take action.

Comment: @CindyMeister while I would love to write an FR but due to the current state we're in I prefer working with what we have. Redirecting users is therefor not an option now.

Comment: Mmm, your question does not appear to be getting much traction. Is it the season, or disinterest, I wonder... Yes, I understand "current state". FWIW I support your idea and would be happy to read/critique any proposal. But I don't feel I have enough experience to try to write something, myself.

Answer (score 16):

> This is the draft proposal for an extra answer on the FAQ question [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917)
> It is Community Wiki, edit at will.

---

## You have a question about your Stack Overflow post

If you opted for asking a question on Meta about your own question (an option available for users < 5 reputation) you're not finished after you clicked the link and are about to hit the *Post your Question* button.

You are about to attract the attention of experienced members of the community to your question. Most of them will have all the available moderation options at their disposal. To have them use their options effectively make sure you give them enough context about what you need help with.

**Do not use this path if your only goal is to expedite answers to your question on Stack Overflow or circumvent a quality ban**

The following structure helps to bring in the context/aspects users need to guide you effectively.

#### Check if your question has been answered before

Stack Overflow community is huge, so it is likely that your question has been answered before and more than once. Although we understand that each situation is unique, the community reached consensus on a general case for a lot of them:

1. [Why am I blocked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) from asking/answering?
2. Why downvoters [do not provide feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin)?
3. How to deal with [revenge downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)?
4. ...and [many more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclosed-questions%5D%20or%20%5Bdownvotes%5D%20or%20%5Bcomments%5D%20or%20%5Bedits%5D%20score%3A1%20answers%3A1%20closed%3Ano)

#### Prepare your question

Address the following bullets in your question.

- My question is (downvoted | edited | closed | commented on | not answered)<sup>1</sup>
- I have read the guidance in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) | [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/) and other Meta posts on what can be done in my situation (describe what you think you should do)
- I have tried to apply (describe your action) based on what I found in that guidance but (pick all that apply)

  - I hoped (describe what you hoped would happen) but (describe what happened instead)
  - I have trouble doing (describe what you have trouble with) and (describe what aspect you want guidance on)
  - I'm unsure if I missed anything and would like someone to review my attempt and receive feedback
  - (an option not listed above, be clear, verbose enough)
- I would like to know if I have done the right things so far or if you have extra tips/guidance I should be aware of

#### After you posted

Be available for responding to comments that ask for clarification. We assume you act in good faith; we love you to return that same assumption (aka: downvotes are about the post, not about you). Re-read [What is Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Be prepared for criticism and [the Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/11407695) as you are essentially requesting a community audit. If you are worried about that, look through your posts and clean up a little - after all, the best *and* the worst of your deeds are the ones most visible.

---

<sup>1. pick one or more</sup>