# Was I right to close this as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How can I start a Vert.x Verticle in debug mode in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63076532/how-can-i-start-a-vert-x-verticle-in-debug-mode-in-intellij)

The answer I received made me realise that I'd made a foolish mistake - akin to a typo. The post I'd originally linked to did indeed answer my question, although not explicitly. I couldn't decide whether I should just delete the question, or leave it there as a duplicate. The reason I originally thought it was worth asking, was because searching specifically for debugging a Vert.x application in IntelliJ didn't find me anything. Leaving my question as a duplicate might help direct other people to the same post, even if their problem isn't quite so user-error-y as mine was.

I guess I feel that my question adds - in a very small and almost insignificant way - to the overall value of the site as a knowledge base. Did I do the right thing?

Comment: I personally see no harm in keeping the question. It seems clear and should be able to serve as a useful signpost. Although I'm not really well versed in the technology there, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: Thank you for being aware of the several features of the site, how you used them as well as how you approached Meta in getting assistance. Well done, appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @rene - I'm not sure if the way I marked it as a duplicate was right - I flagged it for a moderator which felt like a waste of someone's time, but then when I came back a bit later it was asking me if I wanted to accept that it was a duplicate, which seemed weird if that was the response to me flagging it. Maybe someone else flagged it too? Either way, I guess it got to the correct state in the end :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have indeed several options to approach this.

Let me first say that you did well in finding and citing a question that you felt was addressing a similar problem as you had and then explaining what you thought was different in your context.

By doing so future visitors with the same problem might find your question as well as the other one.

I can't judge if your question is a true duplicate but as an [OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) you can "flag" your own question as duplicate and/or confirm a proposed duplicate offered by other community members.

Despite your assessment that your question is maybe a typo and not a duplicate I think having it as a duplicate is the better solution here, assuming it will act as a sign-post.

So to answer your question: Yes, I think you were right to close this as a duplicate.

Let's see and wait what true subject matter experts have to say on this.

Comment: It seems sad that "finding and citing a question that you felt was addressing a similar problem" is noteworthy, but I suppose this is the world in which we live.

Comment: @DPWork it is sad. I'm the author of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392303/i-have-a-question-about-my-stack-overflow-post) to give you some context wrt how you came to Meta. More often then not the users on Meta deal with disgruntled users that somehow ended up in a situation they were warned about / could have known had they read and followed given guidance, etc. It is a relief now and then to have a post that doesn't fall in that same bucket. I'm  doing my best to let you know you are doing The Right Thing ™. It is needed as an example for others to follow.